# How to setup EC2 as simple website with php support?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm an AWS newbie and I can't seem to find a good example. There are plenty of static website examples for S3, but my site needs to run a fairly simple PHP script which then means I need to be on EC2.

I used Elastic Beanstalk to create an EC2 instance and it added a simple PHP example, so when I go to the public DNS address in a browser, I see the example PHP script run. So far, so good.

But, where are those files and how to I access/modify them? They don't seem to be in the S3 bucket that Elastic Beanstalk created.

If I try to Connect to my EC2 instance, it says there's a problem with port 22 and a key pair is needed. Not sure what to do here.

So, how do I upload an html website to run on this instance and still get a PHP script to run?

Sorry if I have some of the terminology or methodology wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> But, where are those files and how to I access/modify them? They don't seem to be in the S3 bucket that Elastic Beanstalk created.

They probably are but in a ZIP package. You don't modify anything on the fly. You're supposed to modify your source code on a local machine, "bundle" it in a ZIP file and then either

1. Upload with AWS Console.
2. Upload it to S3, create an application version with AWS CLI and then deploy (also with AWS CLI).

Docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html

It is possible to change your application by connecting to an EC2 instance, but your changes will be lost during redeployment, scaling etc.

> If I try to Connect to my EC2 instance, it says there's a problem with port 22 and a key pair is needed. Not sure what to do here.

When you created your Elastic Beanstalk environment you were asked for 'EC2 key pair'. You should use that exact SSH key to connect to your instance. This step is optional, so it is possible that you skipped it and created an environment without a key. In this case there is no way to connect to your EC2 instance (almost). You'll have to upload an SSH key (EC2 dashboard -> NETWORK & SECURITY -> Key Pairs) and create a new environment.

Comment: Thanks...this is a start. Do I have to do anything for it to work as a web/html server?

Comment: No. You can just add HTML/CSS/JS to your ZIP bundle. Elastic Beanstalk will create a web server for you and (optionally) create a load balancer.

Comment: Yes. I found out that when I zip my site files, I should not zip the folder they're in, just the files inside. That worked.

Comment: I can't seem to ssh into the instance, though. When I used Elastic Beanstalk to create the instance, it did not say anything about a key pair.